# Folium map view inside a PyQt5 tabWidget by Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium

First of all, i am a beginner in PyQt5 and Python. I would like add a folium map inside a QtabWidget(tabContainer1) **with out using any layout**. I have a Ui file named "mapTezt.ui". I have a searched a lot and couldn't get anything. (#avoid1, avoid2 are QvBox layout that i want to eliminate). help....

[my window, using Q Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Gze.png)

```
    
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, line, sourceID):
        print(msg)  # Check js errors
        if 'coordinates' in msg:
            self.parent.handleConsoleMessage(msg)


class FoliumDisplay(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        super(FoliumDisplay, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("mapTezt.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('B7_Map_view')
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # avoid 1
        self.setLayout(layout)           # avoid 2

        self.tabContainer1=self.findChild(QTabWidget,"tabContainer1") #I want to add folium map inside the tab widget



        coordinate = (8.575589503988725,436.98120117187506)
        m = folium.Map(
            tiles="OpenStreetMap",
            zoom_start=8,
            location=coordinate)

        folium.Marker(location=[8.558954404198643,436.87803268432623],
                            popup='One', icon=folium.Icon(color='purple',prefix='fa',icon='Anchor')).add_to(m)
        folium.Marker(location=[8.908136736259276,436.90841674804693],tooltip="Two" , name="Two").add_to(m)

        A=[8.558954404198643,436.87803268432623]
        B=[8.908136736259276,436.90841674804693]
        folium.PolyLine(locations=[A, B], color='red').add_to(m)
        c1=(A[0]+B[0])/2
        c2 = (A[1] + B[1]) / 2
        angle=90
        folium.RegularPolygonMarker(location=(c1,c2), fill_color='red',color="red", number_of_sides=3, radius=5,
                                    rotation=angle, fill=True).add_to(m)

        # Add Custom JS to folium map
        m = self.add_customjs(m)
        # save map data to data object
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)

        webView = QWebEngineView()  # start web engine
        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        webView.setPage(page)
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())  # give html of folium map to webengine

        layout.addWidget(webView) # Here, i need map view in tabWidget



    def add_customjs(self, map_object):
        my_js = f"""{map_object.get_name()}.on("click",
                 function (e) {{
                    var data = `{{"coordinates": ${{JSON.stringify(e.latlng)}}}}`;
                    console.log(data)}});"""

        e = Element(my_js)
        html = map_object.get_root()
        html.script.get_root().render()
        # Insert new element or custom JS
        html.script._children[e.get_name()] = e
        return map_object

    def handleConsoleMessage(self, msg):
        data = json.loads(msg)
        lat = data['coordinates']['lat']
        lng = data['coordinates']['lng']
        coords = f"latitude: {lat} longitude: {lng}"
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    UIWindow = FoliumDisplay()
    UIWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use a layout. What ***specific*** problem are you attempting to solve by doing so?

Comment: Forgive if iam wrong, i want to hide some more widget and some time this tabWidget also. That's why I don't use layout. If you don't mind how can I add folium map inside a tabWidget.

Comment: Why would using a layout prevent you from hiding the widgets?

Comment: May be my mistake, iam a beginner. please help me to add a folium map inside a QtabWidget.

Comment: Add the layouts and QWebEngineView to the QTabWidget *in Qt Designer*, rather than creating them in code. Do not ever use `findChild` to access widgets: it's unnecessary and bad practice. Instead, use the `objectName` you set in Qt Designer, which `loadUi` will use to create attributes of the same name in your `FoliumDisplay` class. Then you can simply do `self.webView.setPage(page)` etc. There should be no need to create layouts or add any widgets to layouts within your code - so get rid of all those lines. All of that GUI-related stuff should be done in Qt Designer.

Comment: Thanks, i think it will help my problem. Thanks sir...